# Trie Recursion Strange Output

Tags: java, recursion, trie

I've been working on some code that recursively iterates through a trie filled with words.

There are a lot of problems with this right now, but ignoring those, I was wondering why "?"s are printing out here when I have no "?"s in my trie or any print statements?

Here's my code for the recursion portion of my work. Please ask if you need anything else.

```
public String recurse(Node n){//RECURSION
String build = "";
build += n.getVal();
System.out.print(build);
    if(n.getChild() != null){
        recurse(n.getChild());
    }
    if(n.getSibling() != null){
        recurse(n.getSibling());
    }
    return build;
}
```

This is the output I'm currently getting:

```
duck^?free^?good^?real^?hum^?rtful^?duck^?free^?good^?real^?hum^?rtful^?
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**

Here are the words in my trie(i'm using a small number of words to test first):

```
argument
bash
cow
duck
free
good
real
hum
ask
allow
hurtful
```

Here is my Node class:

```
public class Node{
private Node child;
private Node sibling;
private char value;


public Node(char val){
    value = val;
}

public char getVal(){
    return value;
}

public Node getChild(){
    return child;
}

public Node getSibling(){
    return sibling;
}

public void setVal(char val){
    value = val;
}

public void setChild(Node nextReference){
    child = nextReference;
}

public void setSibling(Node nextReference){
    sibling = nextReference;
}
}
```

I filled the DLB trie with the code like this:

```
public boolean add(String s){
    if (s == null)
        return false;
    s = s + SENTINEL; //sentinel is '^'
    StringCharacterIterator iterator = new StringCharacterIterator(s);
    if(root == null){//this is if there are NO values in the trie
        root = new Node(iterator.current());
        Node currentNode = root;
        iterator.next();

            while(iterator.getIndex() < iterator.getEndIndex()){
                Node newNode = new Node(iterator.current());
                currentNode.setChild(newNode);
                currentNode = currentNode.getChild();
                iterator.next();
            }
    }else{
        Node currentNode = root;
        while(iterator.getIndex() < iterator.getEndIndex()){
            while(iterator.current()!=currentNode.getVal()){
                if(currentNode.getSibling() == null){
                    Node newNode = new Node(iterator.current());
                    currentNode.setSibling(newNode);
                    currentNode = currentNode.getSibling();
                    break;
                }else{
                    currentNode = currentNode.getSibling();
                }
            }
            iterator.next();
            if(currentNode.getChild() == null){
                Node newNode = new Node(iterator.current());
                currentNode.setChild(newNode);
            }
            //iterator.next();
            currentNode = currentNode.getChild();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What are the words in the `trie`? Do they have special characters?

Comment: @nicodp no special characters. Just straight letters. That's why i'm confused.

Comment: It'd be useful if you provide the input to your function, that is, the full `Node`

Comment: @nicodp do you mean my node class?

Comment: Yes, and how you construct it with the words.

Comment: I see the relation between them but not exactly sure how you constructed your Trie. But here it goes {duck -> free -> good->real->hum}, these must be the siblings as they are lying on the same level of trie (a,b,c,..z). The last one is however interesting as {hum, hurtful} are children of {hu}. And, the last thing I want to know is, did you print your build again from the calling function as the output after 'rtful' repeats itself all over again?

Comment: @nicodp I've added my Node class and the implementation of how I filled my trie. If there are any formatting issues, please let me know.

Comment: @st1id3r I did not print my build again, to my knowledge.

Comment: Why don't you debug it? See where the ^? gets added within the API of recurse perhaps

Comment: I wrote a similar program just a few days ago. Your add() function may be much more intuitive if you rewrite it as a recursive method having first drawn a flowchart showing the discrete steps and decisions of your algorithm.